# How can I reuse Laravel 5 Collection Filters?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I've got a custom collection sortBy function that I use to sort a model. The problem is, I'm copying and pasting this filter code every time I want to sort it. It seems like this must be beyond best practices since copying and pasting code for reuse is a no no. What is the best practice way to handle this?

For instance, we have Eloquent scopes for reusable query based sorting and stuff like that, but nothing for collections along the same vein.

Comment: Can't you add the sortBy method to the Model class? Everytime you extend Model (with all your models) they will inherit it.

Comment: My bad, you were talking about Collections. So, can't you edit the Collection class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a "helper" function (see Laravel's helpers for where to put this & how to autoload it) and use that wherever you need to sort, like this:

The sort function:

```
function mySortHelper($a, $b) {
    // ... sorting code goes here ...
}
```

And when you need to use it:

```
$collection->sortBy("myHelperFunction");
```

Edit: **Adding a helper function**

Here's the way I've done this in my applications.

In the `app` directory, create a folder called `Helpers`.

Inside the `Helpers` directory, create a new PHP file called (for example) `Sorting.php`.

In this new file, create your function like this:

```
if ( ! function_exists('mySortHelper'))
{
    function mySortHelper($a, $b)
    {
        return $a<$b ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

This code is copied (with changes) from the the Laravel framework helpers file (found at `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php`).

Then the only thing left is the autoloading. Update your `composer.json` file with:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        ...
        "app/Helpers/Sorting.php",
        ...
    ]
},
```

There may be other sections in the `autoload` section of the `composer.json` or other things listed under `files`. Just add the file you created to that section of your `composer.json` and run `composer dump-autoload` to update. Your helper function will now be available throughout your Laravel application.